# How can I upload an image from a gallery to a server in Windows Phone 8.1...?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How can I upload an image from a gallery to a server?

I am using `FileOpenPicker` to pick the image display `BitmapImage` display in screen. This is working fine at the same time image uploaded to the server. I am using this code to pick the image to gallery using  `FileOpenPicker`.

```
 private async void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImagePath = string.Empty;
            FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

            // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

            filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
            view.Activated += viewActivatedddd;

        }



private async void viewActivatedddd(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
        {
            FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

            if (args != null)
            {
                if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;

                view.Activated -= viewActivatedddd;
                StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
                var imageFile = args.Files[0] as StorageFile;

                var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                displayImage.Source = bitmapImage;
                btnclose.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;



            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution when I encountered this issue when leveraging WebAPI.

Convert the image into a memorystream.

Client:

```
 public async Task UploadImage(byte[] image, string url)
        {
            Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
            HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

            Uri resourceAddress = null;
            Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out resourceAddress);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
            request.Content = streamContent;

            var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
        }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    Stream requestStream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await requestStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....but i am not using view model Controller normal structure. frist time i am using windows phone 8.1 .Please add the code to my above methods .

Comment: Your controller is what WebAPI requires to process service calls.

Comment: I am using visuval studio 2013 professional and windows phone 8.1 ,json web services .

Comment: Can you take half an hour to do a WebAPI  tutotial? Then you can leverage my solution for the Server section.

Comment: @ScottNimrod can you upload how did you convert image to byte array in WP8.1?